# How to reverse-engineer a remote control?

Tags: wireless, protocol, reverse-engineering

I purchased a few bulbs which are manged via a wireless remote control. I would like to use them with my RPi (to which I would add the relevant transmitter-receiver module).

Is there a way for a layman who may have access to reasonable measuring devices (and is an ex-physicist) to determine

- the frequency of the transmitter (hopefully 433 or 315 MHz)
- the protocol (when I press the "on" button such and such signal is transmitted, ...)

Comment: I would imagine it would be easier to reverse-engineer the transmitter. In the end that's what you want to emulate. As uint128_t says, it would be much easier to have the Pi short out the buttons on the remote. Something like a CD4066 CMOS switch should do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, find the FCC ID of the device. If they are wireless devices approved for use in the US, there should be an FCC ID somewhere (either on the device proper, or on a wireless module inside the device). Use the [FCC ID Search](https://www.fcc.gov/general/fcc-id-search-page) to look up the device, this should tell you what frequency the device uses. Alternatively, the device might tell you what frequency it uses. Or, take a look at the ICs, and look up the part numbers of everything that looks important. If you're lucky, they use a common wireless SoC with a public datasheet.

Once you know the frequency, things get tricky. If the device operates in the 2.4GHz band, it could be pretty difficult to reverse-engineer it, because the protocol is likely non-trivial. In which case, your best bet would probably be to bodge the existing remote onto the Raspi (using the Raspi to "press" the buttons).

If they use 433MHz or 315MHz, it's possible/likely that they are simply using serial. If you have an existing receiver, you can try looking at the signal (analyzing serial on a scope is very easy, if you have a scope). Or, you could probe around on the transmitter board to find the TTL serial signal and capture that.

Pictures of the devices and their internals could help narrow it down, but that's the general answer.